# how to store integer number into a character pointer in c

Tags: c

I am trying to store character as well as integer numbers in the same region through character pointer however, I am not getting the intended result. It is displaying only characters.
Here, I have created a character pointer which should contain atleast both characters and
integers, then should display them properly.

```
int main()
{
char c,store[30];
char *p=malloc(30);
 int choice,i=0,n;

 p=store;
while(1)
{
 printf("\n********Menu**********");
 printf("\n1.Enter a character");
 printf("\n2.Enter a Number");
 printf("\n3.Enter a double");
 printf("\n4.Display the values");
 printf("\n0.Exit");
 printf("\nEnter your choice:");
 scanf("%d",&choice);

 switch(choice)
 {
 case 1:
     printf("\nEnter a character:");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%c",&c);

     *p=c;

     p++;
     break;

 case 2:
     printf("\nEnter a Number");
     scanf("%d",&n);
     *p++=n;
     break;
 case 4:

     *p--='\0';
     for(i=0;store[i];i++)
         printf("%c",store[i]);
     break;

 case 0:
    exit(0);
    break;
 }
}

 getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all:  Why would you do this???  It's a horrible practice, and shouldn't be done without a lot of extra code to make sure you don't do it wrong.  Second: You're doing it badly - in case 2, you should be incrementing p by sizeof(int) and you need a typecast, Third: When you print, you're using %c to print it as a character.  If it was an int, print it with %d.  Is this an attempted lesson in learning how to use a union?

Comment: What do you think `*p++` does ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply write doubles and int into a `char` array.

However with following you could see 0-9 :

```
case 2:
     printf("\nEnter a Number"); //Just for 0-9   
     scanf("%d",&n);
     *p=n+48; //Convert to ascii
     p++;
     break;
```

Comment: What you will receive if user enter, for example, 11 as number?

Comment: @DanilAsotsky ascii corresponding to 11+48, w.r.t my post